# Puppeteer: another way of getting contents of an iframe besides disable-web-security?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, puppeteer, same-origin-policy

When I use Puppeteer to get the HTML of a page with an iframe, I run into

`DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin [url] from accessing a cross-origin frame`

I understand to bypass this, I can use:

```
puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    args: ['--disable-web-security']
});
```

But is there another way of bypassing the cross domain issue other than using the `--disable-web-security` flag? I'm seeing people online urging the community to not use the flag because it's dangerous as it exposes your local file system.

Comment: as I am writing this, it's not possible to access the iframe by --disable-web-security, how does that work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Chromium. Here is what worked for me:

```
puppeteer.launch({
  executablePath: 'chromium',
  args: [
    '--no-sandbox',
    '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
    '--disable-web-security',
    '--disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process',
  ],
})
```